# How to easily create stacked barplots from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to create plots for two categorical variables, so I thought a staged barplot would do best.
Took a look at the examples of seaborn and matplotlib and hope there is an easier approach.

My dataframe look like this:

```
sex     age-group     category
m       <18           basic
m       <18           premium
f       <18           premium
m       <18           premium
f       18-24           basic
m       18-24           basic
f       <18           basic
f       <18           premium
f       <18           basic
f       <18           basic
```

(there are duplicated rows here, in the full dataset there are additional columns with different values per row)

Now I would like to see the age-group on the x axis and the sex or the category on the y axis staged.

Do I need to create variables with df.query?

Comment: This is pivot count

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index='age-group',aggfunc='count').plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)`